# Separate strings in an array in a certain order

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a list that I took from a converted `CHANGELOG.md` file, and it looks like this:

```
["[3.0.0]","Features", "changes done in file","[2.0.1]", "Bug Fixes", "fixed login"]
```

What I want to do is to separate each version into its own list, like this:

```
["[3.0.0]", "Features", "changes done in file"],
["[2.0.1]", "Bug Fixes", "fixed login"]
```

Obviously, because it's a changelog, there can be multiple features and multiple bugfixes in a single version, so I want to a piece of code that separates the code appropriately.

I tried using `if (string.startsWith('['))` but i couldn't manage to fit it in a loop.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check out my answer, I updated it with a quick description of what the code does.

Comment: If you don't have the character `[` anywhere else in the strings, do a `join` on the initial array and then split on `[`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I came up with. The code basically loops through the input array and adds each string to a currentArray variable. Everytime it hits a `[` it puts the currentArray into the output and clears currentArray. At the end it removes the first element as the first element of the output will always be an empty array (since the first element of the input starts with a `[`)

```js
var input = ["[3.0.0]","Features", "changes done in file","[2.0.1]", "Bug Fixes", "fixed login"];
var output = [];
var currentArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  if (input[i].charAt(0) == '[') {
      output.push(currentArray);
      currentArray = [];
  }
  currentArray.push(input[i]);
}
output.push(currentArray);
currentArray = [];

//Since it will take the first one, and put empty one, need to do last step.

output.splice(0, 1);

console.log(output);
// ["[3.0.0]", "Features", "changes done in file"],
// ["[2.0.1]", "Bug Fixes", "fixed login"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're always working in sets of three, this is a quick and ugly approach

```
var data = ["[3.0.0]","Features", "changes done in file","[2.0.1]", "Bug Fixes", "fixed login"],
    items = [];

data.map( (el, idx) => { 
    var last = items.length; 

  if( idx % 3 === 0 ) { 
    items.push( [] ); 
    last += 1; 
  }

  last = items[ last - 1 ]; 
  last.push( el ); 
} );

console.log( JSON.stringify( items ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution should you prefer it:

```js
const arr = ["[3.0.0]","Features", "changes done in file","[2.0.1]", "Bug Fixes", "fixed login"];
const newArr = [];
let tempArr = [];

arr.forEach(function(v, i) {
  if(/^\[\d+.\d+.\d\]$/.test(v) && i > 0) {
    newArr.push(tempArr);
    tempArr = [v];
  } else {
    tempArr.push(v)
  }
});

newArr.push(tempArr);
console.log(newArr);
```

This snippet loops through the items one-by-one. It uses two arrays, one to hold the final result and one to populate with items for the current version.

I am using a regex to check if the item contains one `[` followed by a number, then a period, number, period, number and finally the trailing `]`. This allows the other strings that are not version tags to contain that character.

If the current item is a version tag, we push `tempArr` (which contains the changes of the current version that we've previously filled in our loop) to our result array `newArr`. Then, we empty the `tempArr` and give it the starting value of the next version tag.

If it is not, we just push the current item to our temporary array.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know if you were guaranteed to get this data in triplets, as your example seems to imply. If you knew this up front, there are many creative solutions that could emerge. For just creating a 2D Array, however, I like this approach (you can run this directly in node.js to try it out):

```
const original = ['[3.0.0]', 'Features', 'changes done in file', '[2.0.1]', 'Bug Fixes', 'fixed login']

function transformToChangeLog (originalArray) {
  const changeLog = originalArray.reduce((newList, element) => {
    element.charAt(0) === '[' // check for version string
      ? newList.push([element]) // If version string, then push a new Array containing that string
      : newList[newList.length - 1].push(element) // If something else, tack it onto the last Array in the changelog list
    return newList // whatever is returned in the reduce function is passed to the next iteration, allowing us to build this 2D array one element at a time. 
  }, [])

  return changeLog
}

console.log(transformToChangeLog(original))
```

I hope that helps! I like the `reduce` Array method, because of it's versatility and succinctness.